# Spring data mongodb auditing information in nested object

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

is ther a way to put information like `@Version` or `@CreatedAt` in seperated nested object?

```
class Document{
   Info info = new Info();
   ...
}

class Info{
   @Version
   Long version;
   ...
}
```

I tought it would be that easy but the fields (version) are not updated (= null). When i put it directly in the `Document` class its working.
Any ideas?